# How find a elements of div with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get "a" elements of the div with class

```
<div class="membox_externalcontent">
    <!-- find "a" elements of here  -->
<div>
```

I have this code for get a element of body and i like to improve it:

```
function xpathh(){
    var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate('//body//a', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );

    for ( var i=0 ; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++ )
    {
        var href = String(nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i).getAttribute('href'));
        console.log(href);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: That code seems completely unrelated to the div in question, nor does it look at classes at all. Did you include the right sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you would in CSS:

```
$('.membox_externalcontent a');
```

you can iterate over those items like

```
$('.membox_externalcontent a').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `find`, you can pass the tag as paremeter.

```
$('.membox_externalcontent').find('a');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using `jquery` :

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/gey78/)

```
var elems = $('.membox_externalcontent a');// array of <a> elements
```

Or :

```
var elems = $('.membox_externalcontent').find('a');// array of <a> elements
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to find all elements contained in a `<div>` with a certain class, it's:

```
var elems = $('.membox_externalcontent *');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming jQuery is allowed, based on the question's tags:

```
var links = $('.membox_externalcontent a');

links.each(
  function( i, v ) {
    console.log(v.href);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a pure JavaScript solution, though I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead.

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    i,
    bar;

for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i += 1) {
    if ((' ' + foo[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' membox_externalcontent ')
            > -1) {
        bar = bar.concat(
            document.getElementById(foo[i].id).getElementsByTagName('a')
        );
    }
}

console.log(bar);
```